# Debugging revel with IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, revel

How can we configure IntelliJ to debug revel apps?

In `Run/Debug Configurations`, it's not at all obvious what to enter for `File`, `Go tool arguments`, and and `Program arguments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your project, for this example i will be using canonical `revel new github.com/myaccount/my-app`

1. Run in terminal `revel run github.com/myaccount/my-app` to generate `tmp/main.go` - this file is **needed** by intellij
2. Select "Edit configuration" to create `Run configuration`. Select `Go Build`
3. Select YOUR file "main.go"
4. Paste in "Program arguments" string `-importPath github.com\myaccount\my-app`
5. Click on "Before launch: ..." and create "Run external tool"
6. There: Program: `<your gopath>/bin/revel`(Windows - revel.exe) Paramerets: `build github.com/myaccount/my-app`, Working dir `<your gopath>/bin`

[Screenshot](https://ibb.co/kkAUKw) Example Config

Now You can Run and Debug in panel IntelliJ